# Register Dropwizard(Spring MVC) application in springboot admin UI

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, dropwizard, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-admin

I have a REST API developed using spring MVC and Dropwizard. I have created healthchecks using the Dropwizard framework. Now I looking how to register this API to Springboot admin so that I can see all the metrics on the admin UI.

I have other API's which are developed using Springboot. So registering them to Springboot admin was very straightforward. But in the other Dropwizard case, I am unable to register it and not sure if I need to do any extra configurations.

Looking forward to the response. Thank you

Comment: Are you trying to register your REST API to spring-boot-admin or are you trying to register your health check urls which are developed with dropwizard

Comment: I am trying to register the healthcheck urls which are developed using dropwizard to springboot admin. Moreover I would be happy to show the dropwizard metrics, logs too on admin page

Comment: It should be no different than registering any url. We are doing this all the time without any problem.